# How to build an webpack app which is fully, transparently, lazily, progressively loaded?

Tags: webpack, lazy-loading, ondemand

## Goals

To build an app which

- is lazily progressively loaded. Only current page(and the pages which need to be preloaded) and it's dependancies (in app or node_modules) are loaded.
- minimizes common chunks. If pageA and pageB depend on same module C, then module C should be only included and load once.
- is friendly to http cache. Changes in some module or page should never invalidate other modules' cache.
- achieve all above in a transparent way. App should be written in the same way as it was bundled into one bundle. I believe the import/export manner in an normal app already provide enough information to do this, except for the lazy load cut points of pages, which can be encapsulated into a thin layer.
- (small fragments is not a problem for me since we expect http 2 to handle them)

## Tries

### Splitting and Lazily Load Pages

Following the [React-Router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/code-splitting) way, we can splitting pages and load them lazily on demand. The problem is, if we don't make it further, pages will contain a lot of duplicate common chunks.

### Load All Modules on Demand

See this [repo](https://github.com/zhaoyao91/docit/tree/show-lazy-app). I made some tools and load *all* modules on demand. The problem is, it is intrusive and not transparent.

## Needed

Solutions or ideas to achieve the goals above.